# Receiving arguments from Twig templates in Symfony2

Tags: php, templates, symfony, arguments, twig

I am developing an application using Symfony2 and Twig for templating. What I would like to know is how I can receive an argument in the controller from a Twig template rendered in the controller. The argument will have the value of a HTML tag attribute. This value will be assigned to the argument mentioned in a onClick event over the HTML tag. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by going:

```
{% render 'YourBundle:YourController:yourAction' with { 'yourVariableName': variableValue } %}
```

where yourVariableName is the same as the variable yourAction is expecting.